# 2 Timers start simultaniously - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, timer

i have been trying to make LolTimer but that does not matter.
For some reason when i click btnStartDragon both timers start running.
If i click the btnStartBaron, this only starts the BaronTimer.

I hope you can help me with this code(its in vb.Net):

```
Public Class Loltimer

'Dragon Timer-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Loltimer_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Timers
    Timer1.Interval = 1000 '// tick every second.
    '// textbox1 = Hours, textbox2 = Minutes, textbox3 = Seconds
    txtDragMin.Text = "6" : txtDragSec.Text = "00"

    Timer2.Interval = 1000 '// tick every second.
    '// textbox1 = Hours, textbox2 = Minutes, textbox3 = Seconds
    txtBaronMin.Text = "6" : txtBaronSec.Text = "00"
End Sub
Private Sub btnStartDragon_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStartDragon.Click
    'Start timer
    If Timer1.Enabled = False Then
        Timer1.Start()
        btnStartDragon.Text = "Running"
        txtDragMin.Visible = True
        txtDragSec.Visible = True
        lblDragonSpawn.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If txtDragMin.TextLength < 2 Then txtDragMin.Text = "0" & txtDragMin.Text '// format from "0" to "00"
    '// verify Minutes.
    If txtDragMin.Text > "00" And txtDragSec.Text = "00" Then
        txtDragMin.Text -= 1
        txtDragSec.Text = "60"
    End If

    If txtDragSec.TextLength < 2 Then txtDragSec.Text = "0" & txtDragSec.Text '// format from "0" to "00"
    '// verify Seconds.
    If txtDragSec.Text > "00" Then txtDragSec.Text -= 1

    'Spawned
    If txtDragMin.Text = "00" And txtDragSec.Text = "0" Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        lblDragonSpawn.Visible = True
        txtDragMin.Visible = False
        txtDragSec.Visible = False
        txtDragMin.Text = "6" : txtDragSec.Text = "00"
        btnStartDragon.Text = "Start"
    End If

End Sub

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



'Baron Timer-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub BtnStartBaron_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnStartBaron.Click, btnStartDragon.Click
    'Start timer
    If Timer2.Enabled = False Then
        Timer2.Start()
        BtnStartBaron.Text = "Running"
        txtBaronMin.Visible = True
        txtBaronSec.Visible = True
        lblBaronspawn.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

    If txtBaronMin.TextLength < 2 Then txtBaronMin.Text = "0" & txtBaronMin.Text '// format from "0" to "00"
    '// verify Minutes.
    If txtBaronMin.Text > "00" And txtBaronSec.Text = "00" Then
        txtBaronMin.Text -= 1
        txtBaronSec.Text = "60"
    End If

    If txtBaronSec.TextLength < 2 Then txtBaronSec.Text = "0" & txtBaronSec.Text '// format from "0" to "00"
    '// verify Seconds.
    If txtBaronSec.Text > "00" Then txtBaronSec.Text -= 1

    'Spawned
    If txtBaronMin.Text = "00" And txtBaronSec.Text = "0" Then
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        lblBaronspawn.Visible = True
        txtBaronMin.Visible = False
        txtBaronSec.Visible = False
        txtBaronMin.Text = "6" : txtBaronSec.Text = "00"
        BtnStartBaron.Text = "Start"
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many handlers:

```
Private Sub BtnStartBaron_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
  Handles BtnStartBaron.Click, btnStartDragon.Click
```

Try changing it to:

```
Private Sub BtnStartBaron_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
  Handles BtnStartBaron.Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the end of this line:

```
Private Sub BtnStartBaron_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnStartBaron.Click, btnStartDragon.Click
```

I suspect that you don't want the second one there.